# SQL how to display each id and its column top 1 value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, devexpress

Hi i have enquiry on how to display based on id and the first value of step ( for example (id 12345 step 0050_01_0100) and (22345 step 0040_02_0300))

For example : the csv file

```
  ID        step

01234     0350_01_0700
01234     0350_01_0700
01234     0350_01_0700

12345     0050_01_0100
12345     0050_01_0100 
12345     0050_01_0100 
12345     0050_01_0200 
12345     0050_01_0200 
12345     0050_01_0300 
12345     0050_01_0300 
12345     0050_01_0400

22345     0040_02_0300
22345     0040_02_0300 
22345     0040_02_0400 
22345     0040_02_0500 
22345     0040_02_0600 
22345     0040_02_0700 
22345     0040_02_0700 
22345     0040_02_0700

15232     0350_01_0700
```

May i ask how can i achieve this?

Expected Output

```
ID    STEP                  ID    step
12345     0050_01_0100     22345   0040_02_0300
12345     0050_01_0100     22345   0040_02_0300
12345     0050_01_0100
```

My code for the .

```
    Dim sql As New OleDbCommand("Select * from [" + csvFile + "] where STEP=(Select TOP 1 STEP FROM [" + csvFile + "]", connx)

 Dim dv2 As DataView = New DataView(dt1)

        dv2.RowFilter = "ID='" + e.Parameters + "'"
```

The outcome of my code

```
 ID           STEP
01234     0350_01_0700
01234     0350_01_0700
01234     0350_01_0700
15232     0350_01_0700
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[ASPxGridView.FilterExpression](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_FilterExpressiontopic)** property is based on the criteria operator syntax, which is described in our Help article: [Criteria Language Syntax](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/CustomDocument4928).

Usually, I suggest users to enable the built-in filter control, put a break point in the DataBound event and check what values are written to the **ASPxGridView.FilterExpression** property when you create a required filter.

Example:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
     gvMS.FilterExpression = ("[DocumentType] = 'Insurance Certificate'")
End Sub
```

> [ASPxGridView - How to get a filter expression from the Filter
>   Builder](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S138003/aspxgridview-how-to-get-a-filter-expression-from-the-filter-builder)
>   The ASPxGridView control provides the FilterExpression
>   property, which returns a string that represents a current filter
>   expression. You can get this property in the server-side
>   AfterPerformCallback event of the control.

**References:**
[ASPxGridView - How to programmatically change the column's filter in the FilterExpression](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18784/aspxgridview-how-to-programmatically-change-the-column-s-filter-in-the-filterexpression)
[ASPxGridView - How to get the syntax for the FilterExpression property](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q319895/aspxgridview-how-to-get-the-syntax-for-the-filterexpression-property)
[ASPxGridView - How to set the Filter expression in code behind](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q488305/aspxgridview-how-to-set-the-filter-expression-in-code-behind)
[ASPxGridView - How to set FilterExpression at runtime](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T267536/aspxgridview-how-to-set-filterexpression-at-runtime)
[ASPxGridView - How to apply the FilterExpression at runtime](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q300804/aspxgridview-how-to-apply-the-filterexpression-at-runtime)

Hope this help..

Comment: but this filter data will be displayed in separate pop up gridview and i have updated my post.

Comment: @Kit: It should be shown in the grid. just handle the call back to get the desired result in the grid rather opening data in separate dialog or screen

Comment: sorry i just realized this can be done from sql rather than rowfilter.